# I'm unsure if the use of "a lot of" in this sentence is correct

Tags: quantifiers

A friend of mine asked me to take a look at his essay, and analyze it for any mistakes. It was overall pretty good, but there was one sentence which got stuck in my mind. I left it out as correct, but I feel like something is off. The sentence in question:

> What’s more, we can listen to music, play video games, and **a lot more things**, easier than...

"A lot more things" sounds kind of incorrect to me, even tho "many more things", which should have the same meaning, is perfectly fine. The reason it's itching me, is because it sounds "loose", if that makes sense. I feel like it should be:

> What’s more, we can listen to music, play video games, and **do a lot more things**, easier than...

"do" in this case helps emphasise that the subsequent "things" in question are all activities. "Can" more or less serves the same purpose, but I still feel like it's necessary. I'm probably just looking way too deeply into it, and it's perfectly fine, but I won't be able to sleep unless I get a concrete answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's ok to start a sentence with "what's more"...

Answer (score 5):

I would agree that

> What’s more, we can listen to music, play video games, and **do** a lot more things, easier than... "

is better and clearer than is the same sentence without the "do". But this kind of omission is common in current English usage. The "do" is not essential, or one can think of it is implied. Many native speakers would say something like this without the "do", and it would not be misunderstood.